# función asíncrona devuelve promise pending en Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de un curso de Node, donde tengo que crear una clase con varios métodos, entre ellos uno que devuelva un array de objetos desde un archivo, usando el módulo fs.
Para ello utilizo una función asíncrona, pero a la hora de instanciar y probar la clase, el return de la función me devuelve 'promise pending'.
Probé de varias maneras, incluso utilizando el método asincrónico de fs.readFile, en cuyo caso en lugar de devolver promise pending, devuelve undefined.
Pego el código a continuación tal y como lo tengo hasta ahora:

```
async getAll() {
    try {
      const contenido = await fs.promises.readFile(this.archivo, "utf-8");
      const datos = JSON.parse(contenido);
      console.log(datos); // muestra el objeto por consola
      return datos; // devuelve promise pending
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En adición a la respuesta anterior, te está dando un promise pending porque lo al momento de agregar un async a tu función significa que esa función siempre regresará una promesa. También el agregarlo te permitirá usar la keyword `await`, que eso te ayudará para poder obtener la respuesta de otras promesas de forma "sincrona" dentro de tu función, por eso el
`await fs.promises.readFile(this.archivo, "utf-8")` te trae el resultado esperado sin tener que ejecutar un `.then()`

Para invocarla efectivamente sería `myClassInstance.getAll().then((res) => console.log(res))`

Este artículo puede ser de ayuda --> https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, de la siguiente manera:
`instancia.getAll().then(res=>console.log(res));`

Comment: deberías de explicar que hace ese código.